Use Vosk speech recognition with Python
I'm trying to use Vosk speech recognition in a Python script, but the result is always :
{
  "text" : ""
}

It's not a problem with my file because when I use in DOS "vosk-transcriber -l fr  -i speech3.wav -o test6.txt" it works perfectly and I got a test6.txt with an accurate transcription.
Here is my Python :
import vosk

# Load the Vosk model
model = vosk.Model("voskSmallFr")

# Initialize the recognizer with the model
recognizer = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)

# Sample audio file for recognition
audio_file = "speech3.wav"

# Open the audio file
with open(audio_file, "rb") as audio:
    while True:
        # Read a chunk of the audio file
        data = audio.read(4000)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        # Recognize the speech in the chunk
        recognizer.AcceptWaveform(data)

# Get the final recognized result
result = recognizer.FinalResult()
print(result)

I downloaded and tried every models available in French (my wav file is in French) on the official Vosk website (4 in total), the scripts run well but give no results contrary to the Windows command...
Any ideas?
Thank you

I'm answering my own question in order to post the final solution to my problem, but it's mainly thanks to Lewis answers and comments below.
Thank you Lewis !
the input .wav file must be PCM 16 bit mono, wich can be obtain with "ffmpeg -i "speech3.wav" "outfile.wav" in windows cmd after installing ffmpeg.
import wave
import json
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer, SetLogLevel


#.wav file must be PCM 16-bit mono !

def vosk(wavFile):
    SetLogLevel(0)

    wf = wave.open(wavFile, "rb")

    model = Model(model_path="voskSmallFr", model_name="vosk-model-small-fr-0.22")
    rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, wf.getframerate())
    rec.SetWords(True)
    rec.SetPartialWords(True)
                    
    text = []    
    while True:
        data = wf.readframes(4000)
        if len(data) == 0:
             break
        # if silence detected save result
        if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
            text.append(json.loads(rec.Result())["text"])
    text.append(json.loads(rec.FinalResult())["text"])

    text=str(text)[2:-2]
    return text



print(vosk("outfile.wav"))


When silence is detected AcceptWaveform() returns True and you can retrieve the result with Result(). If it returns False you can retrieve a partial result with PartialResult(). The FinalResult() means the stream is ended, buffers are flushed and you retrieve the remaining result which could be silence. What you could do is
import json
                
text = []    
with open(audio_file, "rb") as audio:
    while True:
        data = audio.read(4000)
        if len(data) == 0:
             break
        # if silence detected save result
        if recognizer.AcceptWaveform(data):
            text.append(json.loads(recognizer.Result())["text"])
text.append(json.loads(recognizer.FinalResult())["text"])

and you get a list of sentences.Edited:If you want to try to replicate what I did here is the code and the audio I used. It worked.
import wave
import json
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer, SetLogLevel

SetLogLevel(0)

wf = wave.open("test.wav", "rb")

model = Model(model_name="vosk-model-en-us-0.22-lgraph")
rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, wf.getframerate())
rec.SetWords(True)
rec.SetPartialWords(True)
                
text = []    
while True:
    data = wf.readframes(4000)
    if len(data) == 0:
         break
    # if silence detected save result
    if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
        text.append(json.loads(rec.Result())["text"])
text.append(json.loads(rec.FinalResult())["text"])

print(f"\n{text}")


Same result : when I print "text" in your solution at the end of the script, it's just an empty list

@RémiDescamps I tried with 2 sample audio files and it worked. The audio files should be PCM 16-bit mono and you should use a model for the language in the audio. I just noticed that in the code I use rec and you recognizer. I edited the code to correct that.

@RémiDescamps For debugging replace text.append with print to see if it recognizes and print any text between the silences.

@RémiDescamps My audio files are in english and I used the vosk-model-en-us-0.22-lgraph model. You could try to use a bigger model for your language.

well, I tried to replace both text.append with print and I got a empty line and a line with []...I'm using the biggest model for French and it seems to work cause it took about 7 secondes to deliver the empty list.... I just downloaded the model, unzipped it and placed it in the same folder as my script

I'm thinking about another solution : when using the working command "vosk-transcriber -l fr -i test.mp3 -o result.txt" , I'm just sending variables to "Python\Lib\site-packages\vosk\transcriber\transcriber.py" and running it. Problem is, it's object oriented Python, and I don't understand that. Can someone tell me how to use the class transcriber with parameters language, input location and output location ?

@RémiDescamps I edited  the answer and added the code and  the audio I used. It worked. If you want you can replicate what I did.

@RémiDescamps You can but transcriber.py is not supposed to be used directly.  Anyway you can see in cli.py the arguments accepted and the way they are passed to transcriber.
